# Visual Studio Professional 2015 with Updates - Setup Failed

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation

Need help on fixing the Visual Studio 2015 Setup.

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Pro Set up failed.]

I can provide log or other information. Tried uninstalling everything, forced uninstalled everything, removed all the folders still can't get it to install.

Comment: you should dig the logs and find the errors yourself and just post those.

Comment: Yes. Log says that my PC is missing software that Visual Studio installer trying to upgrade. No idea why!? Actually I asked Service Desk to reinstall my windows image so yeah don't have a solution but I CAN NOT spend any more time on this, looks like a solution is to reinstall Windows.